# XML output not coming correct from Function/Procedure

Tags: xml, oracle, function, stored-procedures

I have made a query to get the XML from Database, and the XML Data is coming correctly from the query.
But when i am trying to put that query into a procedure/function to get the XML data from a function/procedure, then the result includes some junk data with the XML data.
Which makes the XML useless as it can't be used by XSLT with garbage data.

Can you please check where i am doing wrong

```
SELECT XMLELEMENT(
         "department",
         XMLFOREST(
           e.dept_id AS "dept_id",
           d.dept_name AS "dept_name"
         ),
         XMLAGG(
           XMLELEMENT(
             "employee",
             XMLFOREST(
               emp_id AS "emp_id",
               emp_name AS "emp_name"
             )
           )
         )
       )
FROM   employees e
       INNER JOIN departments d
       on ( e.dept_id = d.dept_id )
WHERE  e.dept_id = 1
GROUP BY e.dept_id, d.dept_name;
```

This query giving the desired XML data

```
<department>
<dept_id>1</dept_id>
<dept_name>History</dept_name>
</department>
<employee>
<emp_id>1</emp_id>
<emp_name>Helen</emp_name>
</employee>
<employee>
<emp_id>2</emp_id>
<emp_name>Martha</emp_name>
</employee>
<employee>
<emp_id>3</emp_id>
<emp_name>John</emp_name>
</employee>
```

But when we put this query in procedure/function it's showing wrong data as out

```
create  or replace function test_cursor     return sys_refcursor
            is
                    c_result sys_refcursor;
                    po varchar2(20);
            begin

            select headerid into po from staging_orderheader where rownum=1;

                    open c_result for
SELECT XMLELEMENT(
         "department",
         XMLFOREST(
           e.dept_id AS "dept_id",
           d.dept_name AS "dept_name"
         ),
         XMLAGG(
           XMLELEMENT(
             "employee",
             XMLFOREST(
               emp_id AS "emp_id",
               emp_name AS "emp_name"
             )
           )
         )
       )
FROM   employees e
       INNER JOIN departments d
       on ( e.dept_id = d.dept_id )
WHERE  e.dept_id = 1
GROUP BY e.dept_id, d.dept_name;

                    return c_result;
            end;
```

The result of this procedure is XML data from the query but with some garbage value at the start.
Please help

Comment: The function returns a ref_cursor, can't you just parse the result of the cursor back to varchar2 or clob and return that out of the function? Why do you expect to get a valid XML out of a function, that returns a ref_cursor?

Comment: Please edit your question with an example of the (malformed) output it is producing and the code you are using to call the procedure.

Answer (score 0):

`XMLELEMENT` will create an `XMLTYPE` object that stores the structure of the XML but is not a string.

You will probably find that whatever IDE you are using is implicitly translating the `XMLTYPE` object to a string when you run the query in the SQL scope; however, when you return the cursor it is not doing that transformation.

What you will probably need to do is explicitly return the String format of the `XMLTYPE` object using either its `getStringVal()` or `getClobVal()` member functions:

```
create or replace function test_cursor
return sys_refcursor
is
  c_result sys_refcursor;
  po       staging_orderheader.headerid%type;
begin
  select headerid
  into   po
  from   staging_orderheader
  where  rownum=1;

  open c_result for
  SELECT XMLELEMENT(
           "department",
           XMLFOREST(
             e.dept_id AS "dept_id",
             d.dept_name AS "dept_name"
           ),
           XMLAGG(
             XMLELEMENT(
               "employee",
               XMLFOREST(
                 emp_id AS "emp_id",
                 emp_name AS "emp_name"
               )
             )
           )
         ).getClobVal()                   -- Add it here
  FROM   employees e
         INNER JOIN departments d
         on ( e.dept_id = d.dept_id )
  WHERE  e.dept_id = 1
  GROUP BY e.dept_id, d.dept_name;

  return c_result;
end;
```

Comment: Sorry this also giving the same result as earlier.